# Class in the BCL that will event at a given DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timer

Is there an object that will event at a given DateTime or DateTimeOffset?  I am using a Timer to do this operation now but it requires a bit of calculation on my part, was just thinking there might already be something in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how you have to do any calculation:

```
public void StartTimer(DateTime target) {
  double msec = (target - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
  if (msec <= 0 || msec > int.MaxValue) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
  timer1.Interval = (int)msec;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like:

```
System.Timers.Timer _WaitForScheduledTime;
_WaitForScheduledTime = new System.Timers.Timer();
_WaitForScheduledTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WaitForScheduledTime_OnElapsed);
_WaitForScheduledTime.Interval = _ListOfJobs.IntervalUntilFirstJobIsToRun().TotalMilliseconds;
_WaitForScheduledTime.Start();
```

...

```
private void WaitForScheduledTime_OnElapsed(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Debug("Ready to run at least one job");

    // restart the timer
    _WaitForScheduledTime.Interval = _ListOfJobs.IntervalUntilFirstJobIsToRun().TotalMilliseconds;
    _WaitForScheduledTime.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET you may be able to add an empty object into the Cache with a declared ExpirationDate then handle the [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx).  Just a thought, don't know if it will work for you.

If you not using ASP.NET you still may be able to use this trick with another caching framework such as the [Enterprise Library Caching Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309502.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's more complicated/hacky than just using a timer and calculating the interval :)  Nice thought though.

Comment: @spoon16,  agreed its not a technique I've ever used, or needed to, but I heard of it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. I rolled my own class to do that.